# ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias in pig

Tags: user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I am running a pig script which is as follows

```
REGISTER '/home/vishal/FirstUdf.jar';
DEFINE UPPER com.first.UPPER();
A = LOAD '/home/vishal/exampleforPIG1' AS (exchange: chararray, symbol: chararray, date: int,value:float);
B= FOREACH A GENERATE com.first.UPPER(exchange);
DUMP B;

Following is my UDF in java

package com.first;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.impl.util.WrappedIOException;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class UPPER extends EvalFunc<String> {
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try {
            String str = (String) input.get(0);
            return str.toLowerCase();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw WrappedIOException.wrap(
                    "Caught exception processing input row ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Now when i try to run that ,it gives me the following error

```
Pig Stack Trace

ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias B

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias B
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:866)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:683)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:303)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:190)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:166)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:430)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156) Caused by: java.io.IOException: Job terminated with anomalous status FAILED
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:858)
    ... 12 more
```

Whys is that in pig script it is not able to open an iterator for B ie (it is not able to assign an iterator for the following line)

B = FOREACH A GENERATE com.first.UPPER(exchange);

'exampleforPIG1' file has following data

```
NYSE    CPO 2009-12-30  0.14
NYSE    CPO 2009-09-28  0.14
NYSE    CPO 2009-06-26  0.14
NYSE    CPO 2009-03-27  0.14
NYSE    CPO 2009-01-06  0.14
NYSE    CCS 2009-10-28  0.414
NYSE    CCS 2009-07-29  0.414
..
..
etc
```

Comment: Which Pig version do you use?

Comment: Hi Lonard    I am using Pig 0.10.1 .Is the problem version specific?

Comment: Do you use run it locally or on a cluster? If on a cluster I'd check the tasktrackers' logs for more error messages (e.g: outofmemory error) You may also increase the logging level in Pig to see whether it helps to track down the error: (log4j.properties, set the root logger to debug: log4j.logger.org.apache.pig=debug..) With the same setup you have, it works flawlessly for me

Comment: Following is what i got after doing                        log4j.logger.org.apache.pig=debug

Comment: 2013-03-26 09:36:28,054 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - Script Statistics: 

HadoopVersion PigVersion UserId StartedAt FinishedAt Features
1.1.1 0.10.1-SNAPSHOT vishal 2013-03-26 09:36:22 2013-03-26 09:36:28 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId Alias Feature Message Outputs
job_local_0001 A,B MAP_ONLY Message: Job failed! Error - NA file:/tmp/temp1667865178/tmp-477995688,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/home/vishal/BaseballExampleForPig"

Comment: Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "file:/tmp/temp1667865178/tmp-477995688"

Job DAG:
job_local_0001


2013-03-26 09:36:28,055 [main] INFO  org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
2013-03-26 09:36:28,064 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias B
Details at logfile: /home/vishal/pig_1364270780503.log

Comment: Hey Lonard I am running the script in local mode,still I am getting the same issue..What could be the problem   Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the problem is your UDF? What happens if you dump A instead of B? Does it work?

Comment: Hi  AFinkelstein,,yes it is working fine .Where could be the problem

Comment: You sure the files paths are valid? /home/vishal/exampleforPIG1 or /home/vishal/BaseballExampleForPig

Comment: yes jaguarpaw the paths are valid

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 0):

Well two things,

1. If all you want to do is typecast to upper/lower case, why not use the inbuilt functions UPPER/LOWER.
   You can find the usage in the reference manuals.
2. If you want to continue in the same method,
   it should be
   B = FOREACH A GENERATE UPPER(exchange);
   You have already defined it as DEFINE UPPER com.first.UPPER();

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and after breaking my head I found that the flaw was in the input data, even though I was cleaning by replacing null. I had a single record which had fields like '(null)', and it was causing everything to fail. Just check this once, if you have bad records like this.

Answer (score 0):

Its the avro version which caused this error for me.
I was using avro-1.7.6.jar. Changing it to avro-1.4.0.jar solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a pig 0.12.0 or earlier jar against hadoop 2.2, if this is the case then I managed to get around this error by recompiling the pig jar from src, here is a summary of the steps involved on a debian type box

1. download the pig-0.12.0.tar.gz
2. unpack the jar and set permissions
3. then inside the unpacked directory compile the src with 'ant clean jar -Dhadoopversion=23'
   then you need to get the jar on your class-path in maven, for example, in the same directory

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=pig.jar -DgroupId={set a groupId}-
>                    DartifactId={set a artifactId} -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar

or if in eclipse then add jar as external libary/dependency

I was getting your exact trace trying to run pig 12 in a hadoop 2.2.0 and the above steps worked for me

UPDATE
I posted my issue on the pig jira and they responded. They have a pig jar already compiled for hadoop2 pig-h2.jar here [http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.pig|pig|0.12.0|jar](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.pig%7Cpig%7C0.12.0%7Cjar)
a maven tag for this jar is

> org.apache.pig
>          pig
>         h2
>         0.12.0
>         provided

Answer (score 0):

Safe mode is also on of reason for this exception
run the below command

hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave